# How does underscore.js use this._wrapped

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, each, wrapper

I've been reading the annotated source for Underscore.js and I've been wondering how it uses `this._wrapped` when passing the object to the `_()` function as opposed to the typical way of passing the object to a function of the `_` object.

This:

```
_(myObj).each(callback);
```

Versus:

```
_.each(myObj, callback);
```

When I run the first function call and pause it in the developer tools eventually the code ends up here:

```
_.mixin = function(obj) {
  _.each(_.functions(obj), function(name) {
    var func = _[name] = obj[name];
    _.prototype[name] = function() {
      var args = [this._wrapped];
      push.apply(args, arguments);
      return result(this, func.apply(_, args));
    };
  });
};
```

But I'm unsure as to how it knew to go there. Could someone help me understand this? Also, I tried searching for an answer before, but this specific question never seemed to come up. If this has been answered before, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Using Underscore in Object-Orientated Style:

```
_([1, 2, 3]).map(function(n){ return n * 2; });
```

Causes an Object to be instantiated:

```
var _ = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj); // on this line
  this._wrapped = obj;
};
```

The **magic** that can easily be missed is with the absence of the `new` keyword, the function is called like any other function (not as a constructor), `this` will reference the parent scope (and not be an instance of `_`), therefore triggering a `new` statement (and an object construction). It is a very clever way to avoiding forcing the use of `new`.

See https://jsfiddle.net/336493L6/ to see this pattern in action.

All the functions used statically on the Underscore object (each, map etc) are applied to the Underscore prototype using the `_.mixin` function.

This is the line where it happens:

```
_.mixin(_);
```

Of course, if you debug, you'll end up in the `mixin` function as it wraps the static functions.

```
_.prototype[name] = function() {
  var args = [this._wrapped];
  push.apply(args, arguments);
  return result(this, func.apply(_, args));
};
```

This prototype version of the static function, will call the static function with the first parameter set to `this._wrapped`. `result` will not change the return value from the function in this case (it is used for `_.chain`).

Comment: @Tomalak - you have misread it, the second line tests `!(this instanceof _)`, which will be the case if `_()` is called without `new`, however when this runs, it will in turn call `new _(obj)`, which will fail both the first and second if statement and reach the 3rd line.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a JSFiddle showing the pattern I'm talking about